# Scan package.json for deprecated packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

If I go to a package like [react-intercom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intercom) on npmjs, it will display a deprecation warning right there on the page

[image: react intercom deprecation warning]

This seems to be done through a command in npm called [deprecate](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-deprecate).

Is there a way to scan my package.json and find all packages where they have been deprecated?

Comment: As a workaround, you can remove your `node_modules` folder and re-install your packages.  This would show you which packages are deprecated. `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`